# Verified By Visa and mobile devices

Tags: opayo

We've been taking payments online with 3D Secure enabled but a while ago we were getting so much negative feedback from mobile users because the Verified by Visa form in an iFrame was too big for the screen that we turned it off. I've been told that this is no longer financially viable and i need make it work properly for mobiles.

I've wrestled with numerous 'responsive iFrame' solutions but it seems to come down to the iFrame contents that are the issue (tables with hard-coded widths), which obviously I have no control over.

I've not found anything about a mobile-friendly solution after a few hours on the web.

Does anyone know if there is a responsive way to make 3D Secure usable on an iPhone for example?

Answer (score 2):

I think the only way to solve this is to set the iframe’s width to accommodate the fixed width tables (400px should do it) and then apply some CSS to the iframe to scale the page so it fits the mobile screen size.

Here’s an example:

```
<iframe width="400px" height="500px" frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" scrolling="no" src="SagePayURL" style="-webkit-transform:scale(0.7);-moz-transform-scale(0.7);-webkit-transform-origin:top left;-moz-transform-origin:top left;"></iframe>
```

Honestly, I don’t know why VISA or Mastercard can’t have a desktop and mobile version of their 3D secure page.